# Equivalent of Julia's ArgParse range_teser in Python's argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

ArgParse from Julia allows to pass a function for each command-line argument that will check whether the passed argument is admissible (see here: http://argparsejl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/argparse.html?highlight=range_tester). This useful, for example, to constrain a passed argument numeric argument to be positive.

One can do this by manually checking the arguments after they have been parsed, but I think the `range_tester` approach is cleaner. Is there an equivalent funcionality in Python's argparse? I haven't found it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `type` argument of `add_argument`. It can take any callable. See the example for [`perfect_square`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#type) for inspiration.

The following program creates a `type` that accepts an value in a specific range, without using `choice` (maybe good for large ranges?):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

def int_range(start, end):
    def range_type(arg):
        try:
            val = int(arg)
        except ValueError:
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("Invalid value for range (%d, %d): %r" % (start, end, arg))
        if val not in range(start, end):
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("%d not in range (%d, %d)" % (val, start, end))
        return val
    return range_type

parser.add_argument('--foo', type=int_range(10, 100))

args = parser.parse_args()

print("Foo is %d" % args.foo)
```

Output:

```
> python argparse_type.py --foo 0
usage: argparse_type.py [-h] [--foo FOO]
argparse_type.py: error: argument --foo: 0 not in range (10, 100)
> python argparse_type.py --foo bar
usage: argparse_type.py [-h] [--foo FOO]
argparse_type.py: error: argument --foo: Invalid value for range (10, 100): 'bar'
> python argparse_type.py --foo 50
Foo is 50
```

Note that a `argparse.ArgumentTypeError` is raised when the conversion fails. This way, argparse can show the help screen and a custom error message. If a `ValueError` is raised instead, like by the `int` builtin, a default message is shown instead "invalid int value: ...".

Comment: Updated, removed the hack.